# .NET CORE 8 after creating an application don't retain the framework version

Tags: asp.net-core-8

I have recently  installed .NET core 8 SDK. While creating an API application it does show me different version which includes .NET core 8. But when i reopen the solution and check upon the "Target framework". Its empty. i dont even find the core 8 version in list.
[image]

RE-Installed framework.

Comment: Any chance you may have *created* this project in Visual Studio 2022 (which does support .NET 8), and then reopened it in an older version of VS - 2019 or even older? Those *do not* support .NET 8 ....

Comment: Nope, Am sure that i have created & opened project in VS2022.